# How can I change installation direcotory programatically in startup sequence

Tags: install4j

Tried below approach to change the installation directory dynamically through 'Run Script' action in 'startup' sequence but no luck.

```
Util.showMessage("Before getInstallationDirectory" + context.getInstallationDirectory().getAbsolutePath());

context.setInstallationDirectory(new File("E:\testApp"));

Util.showMessage("After getInstallationDirectory" + context.getInstallationDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
```

It showing message still as default installation directory 'c:\program files\testApp'

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: That is the correct approach. Check the log file .install4j/installation.log to see if the installer variable sys.installationDirectory is changed again later on.

Comment: Thanks Ingo for quick response.  I tried the above three statements in single Run script action. No other code/actions executed. Note : I removed .install4j folder from my application installation directory.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an escape character in your path, it should be:

```
context.setInstallationDirectory(new File("E:\\testApp"));
```

otherwise the path is invalid.